# Let $U$ be $~U [0,1] $and let $Y = U^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, problem-solving

Let $U$ be $\sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$ and let $Y = U^{1/2}$.

I'm having trouble finding the $E(Y)$. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: 1. What is the pdf of $U$? 2. What is the definition of $E(Y)$?

Comment: I know the pdf of U is 1 and E(Y) I'm unsure of. That's what is throwing me off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The probability density of a uniform distribution:$$U\sim\mathcal{U}[0,1] \iff f_U(u) = \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}\!(u) = \begin{cases}1 & u\in [0,1]\\ 0 & \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$
2. The definition of expectation of a function of a random variable:$$E(g(U)) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(u) f_U(u)\;\mathrm{d} u$$

So, putting it together: $$\begin{align}\therefore \operatorname{E}(Y) & = \operatorname{E}(\sqrt{U}) \\ & = \int_0^1 \sqrt{u}\;\mathrm{d} u\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: (1) Start with computing the distribution function of $Y$, we have for $y \in [0,1]$:
$$ F_Y(y) = \def\P{\mathbb P}\P(Y \le y) = \P(U^{1/2} \le y) = \P(U \le y^2) = \P(U \in [0,y^2])$$
Now use that $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and hence the probiability of an interval is its lenght.

(2) The density of $U$ is given by $f_Y(y) = F_Y'(y)$.

(3) Now use 
$$ \mathbb E(Y) = \int_0^1 y \, d\P_Y = \int_0^1 yf_Y(y)\, dy $$

Comment: I am still confused sorry.

Comment: @JonDoe With what step?

Comment: of what i'm integrating?

Comment: I don't think I'm following the notation but I clearly get the solution provided two above. that you integrate (g(u)f(u))  where f(u) is the pdf of U and g(u) Y.

Answer (score 1):

Answer using CDF transformation method:

$$F_{Y}(y) = P(\sqrt(U) <y)$$
$$F_{Y}(y)=P(U<y^2) = \frac{y^2-0}{1-0} = y^2 ; 0<y<1$$
$$f_{Y}(y) = \frac{dF_{Y}(y)}{dy} = 2y; 0<y<1$$
$$E(Y) = \int_{0}^{1} y\cdot 2y dy$$
$$ = \frac{2y^3}{3}|_{0}^{1}$$
$$ = \frac{2}{3}$$

Thanks

Satish

Comment: Which is exactly the same thing another answerer did 30 minutes earlier than you.

Comment: I am very slow in typing Mathjax.  I am not defeding my answer to the best, I have given more steps to complete the answer for the OP and I think that is how I see my answer different.  I don't need credit for this but I would like it to be there.

Comment: @satishramanathan I upvoted your answer. I hope it is o.k. for you.

Comment: @calculus, as long as the OP gets the answer, that will be OK.  Thanks for upvoting, it is merely a psychological food that we all yearn for.  Somehow, people have testy exchanges about this 10 points. I am banking professional with different career.  Math is my hobby and wants to be in touch.  Thanks again.